# when test cases assertion failed tearDown doesn't executed on python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have been writing this test cases using python selenium and on the test body i have used assertion and other things instead written them on the page. So i have been noticing something that if any assertion failed during execution it doesn't execute my tearDown method. Is it good practice to write the test cases in this way?

[image: Some of the code snippet]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question.

Comment: def tear down is just a method , what test framework are you using to invoke it ?

Comment: python selenium. with pytest

Comment: @JamesZ Sorry. I will edit this question.